# Pine Script How to add the checkbox in the inputs instead of the dropdown list?

Tags: pine-script

new to pine script and wondering how to change the inputs from dropdown list to checkbox for hide/show? Thank you.

```
highlow = input("", type=input.resolution, title="High")

dailyopenhigh = security(syminfo.tickerid, highlow, high)

line1 = line.new(x1=bar_index-1, y1=dailyopenhigh, x2=bar_index, y2=dailyopenhigh, xloc=xloc.bar_index, style=line.style_solid,extend=extend.right, color=color.blue)
line.set_width(line1, 2)
line.delete(line1\[1\])  // remove the previous line when new bar appears
```

I have tried several approaches and couldn't figue it out.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `input.bool` for the checkboxes.

```
show_highlow = input(defval=false, title="High/Low Lines", type=input.bool)
```

Comment: I tried it gives an error 
"Cannot call 'security' with 'resolution'=input bool. The argument should be of type: string;"

Comment: Why are you trying to use that variable in `security()`? What do you want to do?

Comment: The code plot a trend line on the high of the current bar, when I go to the setting on the chart, it shows High Line and a dropdown menu to select the timeframe. I don't want to show that dropdown menu, I want to use the default high based on the selected chart timeframe. Also, I want to have a checkbox to show/hide that line. Thank you.

Comment: I think using input and security in this context might be wrong and I can use a different coding approach to draw that line, then add input.boot. However, I am not sure how to achieve that task.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles across this in the future:

```
usehighlow = input.bool(defval=true, title="High/Low Lines", inline="HL")
highlow = input.timeframe(defval="", title="", inline="HL")

dailyopenhigh = security(syminfo.tickerid, highlow, high)

line1 = usehighlow ? line.new(x1=bar_index-1, y1=dailyopenhigh, x2=bar_index, y2=dailyopenhigh, xloc=xloc.bar_index, style=line.style_solid,extend=extend.right, color=color.blue) : an
```

[image]

---

If you're not looking to give the user the ability to switch timeframes:

```
highlow = input.bool(defval=true, title="High/Low Lines", inline="HL")

dailyopenhigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '', high)

line1 = highlow ? line.new(x1=bar_index-1, y1=dailyopenhigh, x2=bar_index, y2=dailyopenhigh, xloc=xloc.bar_index, style=line.style_solid,extend=extend.right, color=color.blue) : na
```

[image]